# How to copy an object of a generic class to another object with inherited type?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Because i don't know how to explain my problem clearly,i give an example!
I have these Interfaces and classes:

```
public interface IParam
{
   ....
}

public class Param1:IParam
{
   ....
}

public class Param2:IParam
{
   ....
}

public interface IParamDbService<TEntity> where TEntity : IParam
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
}

public class Param1DbService : IParamDbService<Param1> 
{
   public IQueryable<Param1> GetAll()
   {
      ...
   }
}  

public class Param2DbService : IParamDbService<Param2> 
{
   public IQueryable<Param2> GetAll()
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

And in some cases i need to do this:

```
 IParamDbService<Param> paramDbService;
 IParamDbService<Param1> param1DbService;
 IParamDbService<Param2> param2DbService;

 paramDbService=param1DbService; or  paramDbService=param2DbService;
```

I use `paramDbService` in my code so sometimes i need to copy `param1DbService` into it and the othertime `param2DbService`.but they have different type so i can't do that.Any ideas?

Comment: Your example makes no sense. The return type of the two DbService is `IQueryable<BankKind>` - `BankKind` is not part of your example. Furthermore `Param` is unknown, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it covariant (note the `out TEntity`):

```
public interface IParamDbService<out TEntity> where TEntity : IParam
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
}

IParamDbService<IParam> paramDbService;
IParamDbService<Param1> param1DbService;

paramDbService=param1DbService
```

If you add other methods to the DbService, which get `TEntity` as argument, it is not covariant anymore. You need to split the interface into a `DbReader<out TEntity>` with only the reading part and and `DbService<TEntity>` with everything else.

Alternatively, you could make the writing members based on IParam to make them covariant as well.

Comment: Thankyou.And what should i do in editable mode for the problem above?

Comment: @raha: Lets say you have a method `Update(TEntity entity)`. Your service implements it as `Update(Param1 entity)`. You can't just call it as `Update(IParam entity)`, because `IParam` may be something else. There are several solutions for cases like this. If you have a specific case, ask another question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @ Stefan:Tankyou,yes i think i should use IParam in this case.(Could you please change your answer based on this comment then i can make it as answer.)